# Fixed background image until bottom of page

Tags: css, background, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to get a background image to start and stay in a fixed position, but only until the rest of the 'content' of the page is finished, at which point the full image is displayed.

I'm working on a purely CSS solution. I should note that the image is larger than most (laptop) screens.

Specifically, here's the code that I've been using:

```
body {
  background:$bgcolor;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/cIGSehG.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0px 72px;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  margin:0;
  ...
}
```

The image that I'm using is given in the `url()`:

[image: Background image from snippet]

The effect that I'm looking for is basically the image will display only about the top 10% of the grass hill while you're looking at most of the page, but if you finally scroll all the way down past all the page content, the remaining 90% of the grass hill will be shown.

I couldn't find this anywhere, but I may have just been using poor search terms since I'm not so familiar with the lingo.

Comment: You need to use jquery to find the scroll position and then change the css accordingly.

Comment: Do you want the exposition to be sudden, or gradual from the scrolling?

Comment: Sorry, good question - I'm hoping for it to be sudden, such that the image is totally static until you reach the very bottom of the page.

Comment: @Free It probably isn't applicable to your project, but was my answer of any interest to you? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was one jiggy nut! I did come up with a not so stable trick to achieve this. I don't have time to develop it any more right now, but perhaps it might be a working concept.

#### Main contept

By providing a large and empty footer area that the user is **likely** to hover when reaching the bottom of the page, we use a sibling selector to change the position of its sibling element containing the background:

```
#footer:hover ~ #background {
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Along with a few quirks (which ought to be improved) we can achieve a parallax effect.

#### Go Fiddle

Check out [this JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4PQA/1/) (in Chrome) to see and play with it.